# (Robotium) Action bar up/home button click

Tags: android, android-layout, robotium

I use [**Robotium**](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/) as the library for Junit test for my Android application. I wrote some tests which works well. But when I try to write a test for [native ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)'s **Up/Home button click**, it failed.

My test code is very simple:

```
Solo solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
...
solo.clickOnActionBarHomeButton(); // I expected it will click the Up/Home button of ActionBar
```

I expected the above code will click the Up/Home button of native ActionBar, but it is failed, nothing was happening on action bar. Why??

**P.S.** I am using an Android 4.2.1 device.

Comment: Anything in logs?
Do you have other actions in test code after that click?

Comment: can you put image of your screen & explain where you want to click on screen ?

Comment: Confirm, Robotium 5.0.1 solo.clickOnActionBarHomeButton() not working on 4 devices: 4.0.4, 4.1.2, 4.2.2., 4.4

Answer (score 5):

I use this function:

```
public void clickOnActionBarHomeButton(Solo solo) {
    View homeView = solo.getView(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ? android.R.id.home : R.id.home);
    solo.clickOnView(homeView);
}
```

Maybe it's not a perfect decision, but it works.

Comment: It works to open NavigationDrawer in Robotium correctly.

Answer (score 1):

In our application `Home` button eventually calls `NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask`. When using

```
solo.clickOnActionBarHomeButton();
```

to click `Home` button, it doesn't work. However, I have noticed that `solo.clickOnScreen` clicks on `Home` button reliably. So we use this method instead of `solo.clickOnActionBarHomeButton`:

```
protected void clickOnHome() {
    solo.clickOnScreen(50, 50); //usually hits Home button
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can click the Up/Home button (that is the first ImageButton element in the activity) by using the following code:

```
solo.clickOnImageButton(0);
instrumentation.waitForIdleSync();
```