# Correct way to open NavigationDrawer and select items in Robotium

Tags: android, robotium, ui-testing

What is the correct way to open NavigationDrawer and select items from the navigation list in Robotium 5.1? I tried

> solo.setNavigationDrawer(Solo.OPENED);
>
> clickInList(position);

yet they're not working.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23150545/1006570

Comment: Hi,
This question has been answered here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26118480/how-to-open-navigation-drawer-menu-in-robotium-automation-script-in-android/29645959#29645959

Answer (score 2):

If you examine a navigation drawer activity with `uiautomatorviewer` you can notice that the navigation drawer menu button is the first `ImageButton`. So you can invoke the menu and press the first item through:

> `solo.clickOnImageButton(0);`  // open menu
>   `solo.sendKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN);` // select first item
>   `solo.sendKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER);` // press the first item

Comment: I used solo.clickOnImageButton(0); to open the navigation drawer ... thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

Try this `solo.clickOnScreen(50, 50);` I tried `solo.clickOnActionBarHomeButton();` However sometimes it does not work. Also please refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15835809/robotium-action-bar-up-home-button-click)

Comment: please don't use hard coded coordinates...with many build servers and devices running tests that's a bad and unreliable way