# How to open navigation drawer menu in Robotium automation script in android

Tags: android, automated-tests, navigation-drawer, robotium, junit-runner

I have a application with navigation drawer i want to open the drawer menu in Robotium  automation script.my application minimum Api level is 11 so i am using action bar sherlock for action bar implementation. Please guide me in right way

Comment: solo.clickOnScreen(50, 50);
works. Please refer [this answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15835809/robotium-action-bar-up-home-button-click/23150545#23150545

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I did it by using Navigation Drawer Name Ex `solo.clickOnText("Home");`

Answer (score 3):

none of the methods mentioned in documentation seem to work.
Best option is to swipe rightwards

```
private void swipeToRight() {
        Display display = solo.getCurrentActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        int width = display.getWidth();
        int height = display.getHeight();
        float xStart = 0 ;
        float xEnd = width / 2;
        solo.drag(xStart, xEnd, height / 2, height / 2, 1);
    }
```

This will do this trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following method to open the drawer using Robotium:

```
Solo solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
solo.setNavigationDrawer(Solo.OPENED);
```

Comment: finally i done by using Navigation Drawer Name Ex solo.clickOnText("Home");

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1**:

```
solo.clickOnImageButton(0);
```

or

**Method 2**:

```
solo.setNavigationDrawer(Solo.OPENED);
solo.clickOnActionBarHomeButton();
```

Both the Methods worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can open navgation drawer using content description

```
driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("Open navigation drawer").click();
```